# Installing IPython3 kernel fails

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

I'm trying to install IPython kernel following these instructions (CentOS 7 linux):

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

I'm doing this because I want to upgrade Python execution backend into Python 3.8 in Jupyter.

`python3 -m ipykernel install --user`

gives an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main`
`mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details`
`return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details`
**`import`**`(pkg_name)`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/`**`init`**`.py", line 2, in <module>`
`from .connect import *`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>`
`from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/`**`init`**`.py", line 53, in <module>`
`from .terminal.embed import embed`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>`
`from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>`
`from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager`
`File "/home/asko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>`
`import sqlite3`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/`**`init`**`.py", line 23, in <module>`
`from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>`
`from _sqlite3 import *`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`

Now, when searching solution for this I find these instructions

- install  sqlite-devel package
- re-configure & compile Python from source code

Is this really only way to get the Python kernel in Jupyter upgraded or is there (easier) workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is the only way:  SQLite support must be compiled into Python. Note that it's probably better to build an alternative Python (with `make altinstall`)  than to try rebuilding the default system Python.

Comment: Thanks, compiling Python 3.8 from source solved the problem.